# Confusion between Appengine Datastore db and ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm taking Udacity's Web Development course, which teaches in db.Model. I'd like to do it in ndb instead.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am having a lot of trouble translating the following db.Model code to ndb.Model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def by_name(cls, name):
        u = User.all().filter('name =', name).get()
        # My Attempt:
        # u = User.query(cls.username).get
        return u

    @classmethod
    def login(cls, name, pw):
        u = cls.by_name(name)
        if u:
            return u
```

I believe this set of classmethod aim to return the user entity, given its 'username' property, if it exists. I am grateful for any tip! Thanks for reading.

Comment: ALso have a look at the cheatsheet https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things in ndb have the same name, and work the same way they do as in db, so changing the properties is quite easy. Instead of `.all()`, you call `query` on the model instance. Filtering is done using python comparison operators, with the model's property on the left hand side (the reverse may work as well, never tried it.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def by_name(cls, name):
        u = cls.query().filter(User.name == name).get()
        return u

    @classmethod
    def login(cls, name, pw):
        u = cls.by_name(name)
        if u:
            return u
```